# IISExpress Trace.Writeline output with success request and no debug mode

Tags: asp.net, iis-express

How to view the output of the `Trace.WriteLine` **.Net** function while the application is not in debug mode? It is run with IIS EXPRESS. 
The result is a success status code, not failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use trace.writeline with both mode release and debug the only required thing is in web.config you should have trace enabled.

See this link - [Trace.WriteLine in release mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293585/trace-writeline-in-release-mode)

If you want to output your trace.writeline then you need to add tracelistner.
See following - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.aspx

Following links are example how you can create trace listners.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650498.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2680/Writing-custom-NET-trace-listeners